# Using Server.TransferRequest to force download of file to browser

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I intend to use ASP.NET `Server.TransferRequest` to send a file to the browser without the browser knowing the actual path of the file being downloaded. For example, the address `download.aspx?id=123` should result in the browsers Save dialog popping up.

When I use `Server.TransferRequest` to "redirect" to, say, a PDF file, the contents of the PDF file is sent to the browser; however, the content is shown in the browser window as - not surprisingly - unintelligible text.

I think there should be some headers attached to the response to force the browser to download the file, but "Content-disposition" header doesn't do the trick.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Are you using TransmitFile?

Comment: @Kramb Actually I'd forgotten about TransmitFile thinking it loads the entire file in memory. However I intended the file download process to be resumable, and now I suspect TransmitFile won't allow for that.